# How can use case when in between join in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How can write query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
    case when @id=1 then
        join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.t1id
    else
        join table3 t3 on t1.id=t3.t1id
    end t1
```

Please help

Comment: You can't. But you could `JOIN` both tables and put `CASE` expressions in your `SELECT` to pick the values from the table you want.

Comment: Your JOIN operations are same for @id=1 and @id<>1 then why do you want to put case statement?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Pretty sure that last join should be table3, otherwise its the same as the table2 join. Update the question if it is.

Answer (score 3):

is this helpful.?

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 t1
    LEFT join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.t1id and @id=1
    Left join table3 t3 on t1.id=t3.t1id and @id<>1
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `OR`. Instead of `CASE`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2
        on
        (
            (
                @id=1
                AND
                t1.id=t2.t1id
            )
            OR
            (
                @id<>1
                AND
                t1.id=t2.t1id
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will same result as you wish

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
    case when @id=1 then
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.t1id
LEFT JOIN table2 t3 on t1.id=t3.t1id
WHERE (@id=1 AND t1.id=t2.t1id) 
 OR (@id<>1 AND t1.id=t3.t1id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `CASE` like that.

Just use `IF` to choose the query as a whole and not fragments like that because it won't work in SQL server.

```
IF (@id = 1) BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1id
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.t1id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Dynamic SQL in SQLServer

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
Declare @id int
Set @id = 2
Set @sql = 'select * from table t1'
if @id = 1
Begin
set @sql = @sql + ' join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.t1id'
End
else 
Begin
set @sql = @sql + ' join table2 t3 on t1.id=t3.t1id'
End

Execute sp_executesql @sql
```